# How to Add Records to 2sxc data from DNNSharp's Action Form

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

We have DNN Sharp's Action Form being used by client-partners to post new job listings. The Locations and Categories for these jobs are managed in a little 2sxc apps. We want to extend the ActionForm a little so that the user has the ability to add a new Location or Category when they post the job listing.

What method/action would I use in Action Form to be able to add a record to Locations or Categories data which are both inside the 2sxc App?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no quick way, because there is no adapter. You could create some manual code or create an adapter - but that's probably a day or so of work since you probably don't know the Action-Form APIs for all that.

But if you do do it, please share :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar project. I wanted a form configuration tool for commonly used forms so that a staff person could fill out date, price etc. without getting under the hood.

I kludged it together using

```
var formFields;//Angular Controller For Form Fields
formFields = getScope('ActionFormCtrl').form.fields;
```

Then shoved in my 2SXC values

```
formFields.EventDate = "@Content.SessionDates";
formFields.$digest();
```

This is definitely not the angular way but it does work. Note that you need to run the JS after the form is rendered.